# Search for a single exact word in a SQL column of type varchar and has FULLTEXT index

Tags: php, sql

I have a database column named `category` of type varchar. the column has **two** entries of string type.

1. "review xbox pc"
2. "preview playstation"

I want to search the column for a single word. e.g "review" using the SQL `LIKE`. eg `SELECT data FROM tableName WHERE category LIKE '%review%'`. The query will bring back results of both entries of the column because "preview" consists of the word "review".

I decided to use the SQL `MATCH AGAINST` But there were `0` results. N.B the column is indexed as FULLTEXT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With like will be as following:

```
SELECT data 
FROM tableName 
WHERE category LIKE 'review %' --start of the text
OR category LIKE '% review %' --middle of the text
OR category LIKE '% review'    --end of the text
```